# How to solve this equation with Duhamel integral?

Tags: differential-equations, integral-equations

How do I solve a differential equation with Duhamel's integral? I tried to solve it with NDSolve & LaplaceTransform But nothing works
x[t] == -0.3375*!(

```
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(t\)]\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(g\), \(''\)]*\[Tau]*
    Exp[\(-0.4461\) \((t - \[Tau])\)]*
    Sin[2.974*\((t - \[Tau])\)] \[DifferentialD]\[Tau]\)\)
```

[image]

Comment: Are $x(t)$ and $x_g(t)$ same function or $x_g(\tau)$ means something different?

Comment: this is multiple degree of freedom motiom equation.`Subscript[x, g]` is the movement of the earth that is simplified of `Subscript[x, g] (t)` . Which in the first moment is equal to zero

Comment: Ok! And what is $x(t)$ in this equation?

Comment: Floor displacement

Comment: What function is given and what function to be computed in this equation?

Comment: `Subscript[x, g]` is the force applied to the structure, which can be a triangular, linear or even earthquake force. For convenience, `Subscript[x, g]` can be assumed to be a proximal graph that is zero at zero, 1000 N at 0.2 seconds, and zero at 0.4 seconds.

Comment: Let suppose that function $x_g(\tau)$ is given and two time differentiable. We need to compute the function
$$x(t)=A\int_0^t{x_g''(\tau)e^{-c(t-\tau)}\sin \omega (t-\tau)d\tau}$$ 
with $A=-0.3375, c=0.4461, \omega =2.974$. Is it correct?

Comment: yes it is correct